# Python: Generate random time series data with trends (e.g. cyclical, exponentially decaying etc)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, time-series

I am trying to generate some random time series with trends like cyclical (e.g. sales), exponentially decreasing (e.g. facebook likes on a post), exponentially increasing (e.g. bitcoin prices), generally increasing (stock tickers) etc. I can generate generally increasing/decreasing time series with the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vol = .030
lag = 300
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000) * sqrt(vol) * sqrt(1 / 252.)).cumsum()
plt.plot(df[0].tolist())
plt.show()
```

But I don't know how to generate cyclical trends or exponentially increasing or decreasing trends. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You can use `np.random.exponential`...

Comment: The simplest thing is to add noise to the trend you want. E.g., compute an exponential curve, and corrupt it with additive Gaussian noise. You can filter it to give some momentum, too.

Comment: Have you considered sine or cosine functions to add cyclicality?

Comment: If you want to code it yourself, it is not that complicated. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466979/modify-code-to-get-synthetic-data-that-trends-smoothly/56467512#56467512

Answer (score 11):

You may want to evaluate [`TimeSynth`](https://github.com/TimeSynth/TimeSynth)

*"TimeSynth is an open source library for generating synthetic time series for *model testing*. The library can generate regular and irregular time series. The architecture allows the user to match different *signals* with different architectures allowing a vast array of signals to be generated. The available *signals* and *noise* types are listed below."*